# closedness and convexity of a subset implies completeness

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Actually I want to know that Is it true that a non empty closed,convex subset $C$ of a normed space $E$ is complete  ?

Answer (score 3):

Not Necessarily . Take $(c_{00}, ||.||_{\infty})$, where $c_{00}$ is the set of all real valued sequence with atmost finitely many terms non-zero. Take the set itself as its subset. It is not complete. Or if you are worried about proper subset take the closed unit ball in that space. It is not complete.

If you take the normed linear space $E$ to be Banach then any closed subset is Complete. You need not to have convexity.

Answer (score 1):

No. For instance, if $E$ itself is not complete, take $C=E$.

Answer (score 1):

No. Take for example $C=E=C([0,1])$ endowed with the norm $$ \Vert f\Vert_2 = \sqrt{\int_0^1 f(x)^2 dx}.$$ 
On the other hand, if the normed space $E$ is complete then any closed subset $C$ is complete too (no need of convexity).